# sessionStorage expiring on reload

Tags: javascript, html

As I understood it HTML5's `sessionStorage` is intended to last the duration of a single user session assuming a given website. This means that it should survive reloads or page-to-page navigation within the given site. I think it should even survive if you navigate off a site and then come back within the same browser tab.

In any event, I have no problem saving the information to the sessionStorage with `sessionStorage.setItem('foo','bar')` but as soon as I reload or go to another page on the same site I loose my session storage.

I'm using the latest Chrome on OSX (if that matters). Here's what my session storage looks like in Chrome's debugger (when it's set):

[image]

[image]

And then after a reload of the same page:

[image]

Comment: can you makesure nobody is overriding the stored value of reload of the page

Comment: Try adding an `storage` event handler to see whether any update is happening

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm certain no one else is overriding but listening for an event is a good idea I hadn't thought of. Need to attend to my "day job" but will try this out later in the week once I have time. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: let me know the results